# Get hash url parameters to redirect to requesting url when using Auth0 with Angular 2

Tags: angular, auth0

Auth0 requires you to whitelist callback URLs after authentication so you can't just login on any page in your application with URLs like /thing/1, /thing/1001 as there's no way to wildcard the thing IDs.

This [Github conversation](https://github.com/auth0/wp-auth0/issues/29#issuecomment-252040395) points to neat solution which I have interpreted in Angular 2 as:

In my auth.service.ts:

```
lock = new Auth0Lock('Client_ID', 'Domain', {
        auth: {
            redirectUrl: window.location.origin + '/login',
            responseType: 'token',
            params: {
                scope: 'openid name email',
                state: JSON.stringify({pathname: window.location.pathname})
            }
        }
    });
```

I can then whitelist my /login route in Angular 2. I tried getting my login.component.ts to read and then navigate to the pathname returned by Auth0 in the call back like this:

```
this.route
    .queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
         this.state = params['state'];
         this.router.navigate(this.state, {preserveQueryParams: true});
     });
```

...but params always seems to be empty. As far as I can tell this is because the call back URL is of this form:

http://localhost:5555/login#access_token=...&id_token=...&token_type=Bearer&state=%7B%22pathname%22%3A%22%2Flogin%22%7D

...and Angular 2 routing automatically strips off the # parameters before they get to the LoginComponent.

I then spotted that authResult on lock.authenticated still contains my state parameter in auth.service.ts so attempted to navigate to it as follows:

```
this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult:any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    let state: string = JSON.parse(authResult.state);
    this.router.navigate([state.pathname], {});
```

This seemed to work initially but, it turns out, not reliably...it seems to redirect me unpredictably anywhere from

```
/thing/1001 to 
/things or even 
/
```

...and I can't work out why. Any help very much appreciated.

**EDIT In response to @shusson's answer:**

Working code based on @shusson's answer is in auth.service.ts:

```
export class Auth {
    // Configure Auth0
    lock = new Auth0Lock('Client_ID', 'Domain',{
        auth: {
            redirectUrl: location.origin + '/login',
            responseType: 'token',
        }
    });

    constructor(private router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {

        // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult:any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            let state: any = JSON.parse(authResult.state);
            this.router.navigate([state.pathname], {});
        ...
     }

    public login() {
        // Call the show method to display the widget.
        this.lock.show({
            auth: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'openid name email',
                    state: JSON.stringify({pathname: this.router.url})
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

**EDIT: based on [this comment](https://auth0.com/forum/t/redirect-with-call-back-hash-url-parameters-angular-2/4420/2?u=theotherdy) re: passing paths in callback being a CSRF vulnerability:**

Final working code in my auth.service.ts is:

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UUID } from 'angular2-uuid/index';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    // Configure Auth0
    lock = new Auth0Lock('Client_ID', 'Domain',{
        auth: {
            redirectUrl: location.origin + '/login',
            responseType: 'token',
        }
    });
    //Store profile object in auth class
    userProfile: Object;

    constructor(private router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {

        // Set userProfile attribute of already saved profile
        this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

        // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult:any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            let pathname_object: any = JSON.parse(authResult.state);
            let pathname: any = localStorage.getItem(pathname_object.pathname_key);
            //get rid of localStorage of url
            localStorage.removeItem(pathname_object.pathname_key);
            //navigate to original url
            this.router.navigate([pathname], {});

        // Fetch profile information
        this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error:any, profile:any) => {
            if (error) {
                // Handle error
                alert(error);
                return;
            }

            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.userProfile = profile;
            });
        });
    }

    public login() {
        //generate UUID against which to store path
        let uuid = UUID.UUID();
        localStorage.setItem(uuid, this.router.url);
        // Call the show method to display the widget.
        this.lock.show({
            auth: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'openid name email',
                    state: JSON.stringify({pathname_key: uuid})
                }
            }
        });
    };
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our auth service we do something something like:

```
const options: any = {
    auth: {
        redirectUrl: location.origin,
        responseType: 'token'
    },
};

constructor(private router: Router) {
    new Auth0Lock(environment.auth0ClientId, environment.auth0Domain, options);
    ...
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
        ...
        this.router.navigateByUrl(authResult.state);
    });
}

public login() {
    this.lock.show({
        auth: {
            params: {state: this.router.url},
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: That's done the job thanks @shusson. The only change I had to make was was that I had to set the redirectUrl in instantiation of Auth0Lock, otherwise Auth0 seemed to ignore it. I'll edit above. I also had a reply on the Auth0 forum: https://auth0.com/forum/t/redirect-with-call-back-hash-url-parameters-angular-2/4420/2 suggesting that it would be better to store the path-to-return-to in localStorage against a random UUIDv4 key, send that in the state and then use it to recall the path in .on('authenticated') as "storing the entire routing information in state can lead to CSRF vulnerabilities"

Comment: Good to hear. I've fixed the error you mentioned, I actually do the same in our service (I thought for the example I'd try and be more concise :p). Do you know how storing the entire routing information in state leads to CSRF vulnerabilities?

Comment: No problem - it set me on the right track. I've asked on the Auth0 forum - https://auth0.com/forum/t/redirect-with-call-back-hash-url-parameters-angular-2/4420/5?u=theotherdy